# ChartJS right Y-Axe ticks issue

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I'm having a problem when I', trying to use the right Y axe, looks like the ticks are in the right side of the number, and I can't find a way to put it in the right position, This issue just happen with the right Y axe.

And also the first tick of the chart looks overlapped.

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I fixed it changing the layout paddinG